# Place UICollectionViewCells along an arc (UIBezierPath)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, trigonometry, uibezierpath

I would like to place UICollectionViewCells along the circular arc (UIBezierPath). Please suggest a formula to calculate center of these cells.

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

}
```

All these cells are of same constant size, say (100, 100) and x distance (horizontal) between two cells is also constant, say 20.

```
let startAngle: Double = 0
let endAngle: Double = 180
var arcRadius: CGFloat = 414   // Actually updated dynamically when layout changes
var arcCenter: CGPoint {
    get {
        return CGPoint(x: contentView.bounds.width/2, y: contentView.bounds.height/2 - arcRadius)
    }
}

func drawArc() {
    contentView.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
        if $0 is CAShapeLayer {
            $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
    // Create an arc
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter,
                            radius: arcRadius,
                            startAngle: degreesToRadians(value: startAngle),
                            endAngle: degreesToRadians(value: endAngle),
                            clockwise: true)
    // Create a shape layer and add path
    let shapeLayer = createShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    contentView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using parametric equation of circle. Here is my code -

Create a `Circle` object and then call its func `point(startAngle: forItemAtIndex:)` to find the center point for these cells.

```
struct Circle {
    var center: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    func point(startAngle: Double, forItemAtIndex index: Int) -> CGPoint {
        /*
         This is based on parametric equation of a circle with center (cx, cy) -
         x = cx + radius*cos(angle)
         y = cy + radius*sin(angle)
        */
        var deltaX: CGFloat = 122  // Fixed horizontal (x) distance between 2 cells' centers
        var deltaY = radius - sqrt(pow(radius, 2) - pow(deltaX, 2))  // formula to calculate vertical distance between cells' centers
        var actualY = center.y + radius - deltaY
        var deltaAngleRadians = asin((actualY - center.y)/radius)
        var deltaAngle = radiansToDegrees(value: deltaAngleRadians)
        var stepAngle: Double = deltaAngle - startAngle
        var actualAngle = startAngle + (Double(index)*stepAngle)
        let viewCenterX = radius * cos(degreesToRadians(value: actualAngle)) + center.x
        let viewCenterY = radius * sin(degreesToRadians(value: actualAngle)) + center.y
        var position = CGPoint(x: viewCenterX, y: viewCenterY)

        return position
    }
    func bezierPath(startAngle: Double = 0, endAngle: Double = 180, clockwise: Bool = true) -> UIBezierPath {
        return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: degreesToRadians(value: startAngle), endAngle: degreesToRadians(value: endAngle), clockwise: true)
    }
    func degreesToRadians(value: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(value * .pi / 180.0)
    }
    func radiansToDegrees(value: CGFloat) -> Double {
        return Double(value * 180.0 / .pi)
    }
}
```